# increasing depth of extent tree in ext4

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

How can I increase the depth of an extent tree? How much space should be allocated? To be more precise I only need the depth to be more than 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ext4, an inode uses 60 bytes to address 4 extents by default (12bytes for the header + 4*12bytes for the extents). Every extent can hold data up to 128MiB (by default).
If a file is larger than 4*128MiB (> 512MiB) ext4 is building an extent tree for that. So you'll reach depth = 1 with that.

Now the question is when will you reach depth=2. I tried with a file of ~700MiB and checked the extent depth which was 1. Then I opened the fs-block indexed by the extent and analysed the header.

```
    0A F3 06 00 54 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

It has the typical magic number of f30A and the next two bytes should indicate the number of extents. (in this case=6 which makes sense because 700/128 = 6).
The next 2 bytes 0154 should indicate the maximum number of extents (according to the header information) which comes up to 340 in my case.

-> so why 340? If we look at the actual fs-block size of ext4 the default is 4096 bytes.
Each index consists of 12 bytes. 340*12 = 4080 + 12 for the header = 4092 so it is the max number of extent-info that can fit into this fs-block.

If I interpret this correctly, you can save up to 340 other pointers/leaves/indexes in this fs-block. Each of these 340 refer to an extent (which can hold up to 128MiB)
-> so it comes to: 340*128MiB ~ 43,5 GiB

Additionally each inode can hold up to 4 extents. So I guess this number needs to be multiplied by 4 even though.

```
    -> so I think your file should be > 4*340*128MiB ~ 174GiB to reach depth=2
```

I have not yet tested this hypothesis, but I will try it soon. Meanwhile if someone can proove me wrong, I'm happy as well. :)

Comment: Thank you, if this is really so(I can't see why it shouldn't be), it's very sad :)) anyway thanks once again, if you try it, before I do, let me know.

Comment: @NellieDanielyan more simple to do this https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249598/360526